# Testar Expressão conforme usuário digita

Tags: c#, winforms, eventos

Estou tendo problemas, ao tentar testar uma expressão conforme o usuário digita.

Tenho um `TreeList` onde o usuário vai digitar um código, esse código tem o modelo:

- XXXX-XXXX-XXX

Ou seja, pode ser qualquer coisa do tipo:

- A216-0450-001
- X515-0477-A44
- F6FJ-0000-11C

E por ai vai, então criei um evento `EditorKeyUp`:

```
treeList1.EditorKeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(this.Check_Pattern);
```

Que dispara o método `Check_Pattern`:

```
private void Check_Pattern()
{
    TreeListNode tete = treeList1.FocusedNode;

    string input = tete.GetDisplayText("Descrição").ToString();

    string pattern = @"^.{4}-.{4}-.{3}$";

    if (Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("top " + input);
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

Mas quando digito o ultimo carácter, ele dispara o evento, porém, o valor obtido na `String Input` é o valor anterior.

É como se eu precisasse confirmar a entrada do carácter.

Por exemplo: digitei `A216-0450-001` o valor obtido é `A216-0450-00`, ai quando eu digito `A216-0450-0012` ele retorna `A216-0450-001`

Precisava que quando fosse digitado o ultimo digito, no caso o carácter `1`, fosse disparado o evento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para resolver o problema utilizei o método: [PostEditor](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseBaseView_PostEditortopic)

Utilizei o método `PostEditor`, para salvar a entrada do usuario, e então, poder fazer a comparação.

Pois, se não fizermos a chamada do método, `PostEditor`, ele so ira salvar a alteração, quando mudar o focu da celula.

```
    private void Compare_String(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        treeList1.PostEditor();

        TreeListNode tete = treeList1.FocusedNode;

        string input = tete.GetDisplayText("Descrição").ToString();

        // se o flyout estiver visivel e o usuario começar a digitar ele oculta, se o input for menor que 10 caracteres ou maior que 18 caracteres
        if (input.Length < 10 || input.Length > 18)                
        {
            flyoutPanel1.HideBeakForm();
        }

        string pattern_1 = @"^.{4}-.{4}-.{0}$"; // xxxx-xxxx-         
        string pattern_2 = @"^.{4}-.{4}-.{1}$"; // xxxx-xxxx-x
        string pattern_3 = @"^.{4}-.{4}-.{2}$"; // xxxx-xxxx-xx
        string pattern_4 = @"^.{4}-.{4}-.{3}$"; // xxxx-xxxx-xxx
        string pattern_5 = @"^.{4}-.{4}-.{3}-$"; // xxxx-xxxx-xxx-
        string pattern_6 = @"^.{4}-.{4}-.{3}-.{1}$"; // xxxx-xxxx-xxx-x
        string pattern_7 = @"^.{4}-.{4}-.{3}-.{2}$"; // xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xx
        string pattern_8 = @"^.{4}-.{4}-.{3}-.{3}$"; // xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx
        string pattern_9 = @"^.{4}-.{4}-.{3}-.{4}$"; // xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx
        string pattern_MP = @"^.{2}-.{0}$"; // xx-

        if (Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern_1) || Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern_MP) || Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern_2) || Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern_3) || Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern_4)
            || Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern_5) || Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern_6) || Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern_7) || Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern_8) || Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern_9))
        {
            //exibi o flyout, no ponto medio da celula em x, e no top em y
            flyoutPanel1.ShowBeakForm(treeList1.PointToScreen(new Point(Get_Middle_Node(), Get_Rectangle_Node().Top)));

            //como o metodo Populate_Grid_Itens, esta ligado ao evento  Showing, que é disparado somente quando o flyuout é exibido, se ele 
            //ja estiver visivel, precisamos disparar o metodo abaixo, para repopular o grid
            if (flyoutPanel1.Visible == true)
            {
                Populate_Grid_Itens(this, new FlyoutPanelEventArgs());
            }
        }
    }`
```

Comment: Amigo, Fiz uma revisão, favor verificar se esclarece o problema.